# Is it a bad programming practice setting DOM elements as global variables in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, I have this **HTML**:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    initFields();
});
</script>

<input id="input" type="text">
```

And my **JS**:

```
var $input;

function initFields() {
    $input = document.getElementById("input"); //or $('#input) in jQuery
}
```

This way, I can access `$input.value` at any time (for example when submitting a form, or cleaning the field, etc), so that the variable becomes reusable. My doubt is: is it considered a bad practice to set DOM elements as global variables?

Comment: in a word yes, as your code gets bigger it can be fun to debug it, however it's fine for small bits of code, this is where closures come in (self calling functions), you may have seen init functions where all the global variables are assigned inside a function bit like a class in c# or java

Comment: If you are using jquery you dont need getElementById. Just use $('#input') then $input.val()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes global variables are unavoidable, but they're always regrettable. I would recommend creating one global object, and filling it up with references to DOM elements you want to refer to.

E.g., in the global scope:

```
var $elements = {
    $input  : $('#input'),
    $header : $('#header'),
    // etc, etc
};
```

Bear in mind that all global variables are just properties of the `window` object. One of the bigger issues in creating global variables in javascript is that you might accidentally overwrite a property on `window`, which can have serious consequences that are difficult to debug. If you're only defining one global variable (as in this example), you probably won't run into trouble, but if you're defining dozens of variables for different DOM elements or whatever, your program may quickly become hard to maintain, and hard to debug.